# how to attach and detach a plugin method

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

i am trying to detach and then reattach a jquery plugin method to a div based on true or false returned by an external function. Using unbind i am able to detach the accordion() method from the div, however i am unable to rebind the accordion method again to the div. Once the unbind method is executed then even if the condition return true,  "$('.container').accordion()" code doesn't work. please suggest the correct way to unbind a plugin method and then bind it again.

Below is the sample code for your reference-

HTML:

```
<div class="container" onmousedown="abc()">
```

Javascript:

```
function abc(){
  if (true) {
    $(".container").accordion();
  } else {   
    $(".container").unbind();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `unbind`; use the "destroy" command instead.

For instance:

```
function abc(){
  if (/* condition */) {
    $(".container").accordion();
  } else {   
    $(".container").accordion('destroy');
  }
}
```

See the [docs](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion#method-destroy).  It may be more appropriate to use the `enable` and `disable` commands instead, depending on your circumstances.

Comment: @user713332 Glad to help. If an answer has resolved your question, you can [mark it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

it's because once you unbind the accordion it's doesn't have that method...so you need to bind it again...what you can do is call your accordion js every time...

```
function abc(){
  if (true) {
    $.getScript("accordion.js", function(){
    alert("reinitialized");
    });
    $(".container").accordion();
  } else {   
    $(".container").unbind();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have direct answer, but seems got a clue.

You should check, what class is being added to your div, then you apply accordion() pluing on that. It could be easy see by Firebug. Since it is clear, code would be

```
function abc(){
  if (!$(".container").hasClass('some_accordion_class')) {
    $(".container").accordion();
  } else {   
    $(".container").destroy();
  }
}
```